# How to compare dates and call a function in php

Tags: php

I would like to be able to find a way to be able to execute a function automatically for each date that a user has saved in the database, the function what it does is suspend a service and I would like to know how to make it suspend every 24 hours of automatically without the user having to enter the page to have the service suspended.

This is the function that suspends the service when the user logs in but does it only when the user loads the page and I would like it to do so without having to log in.

```
function SuspendServer() {
  $user = $pterodactyl->users->suspend($id);
}
```

Comment: You're tackling this from the wrong end, basically. Track the last time the user accessed the page. Check if it's been more than 24 hours. Consider it suspended if it has.

Comment: I think I explained it wrong, what I want to do is something like a one day subscription and I don't know how to go about detecting if I finished or not without the user having to enter to see if I finished or not.

Comment: You explained it fine, I'm explaining that there's an easier solution. The subscription is ended if it's been 24 hours since it started, right? Then store the date/time it started, and check against the current time.

Comment: If you want to do it your way, use a cron job or the database's Event Scheduler to run a query periodically. It can look for all records that have an old date and mark them suspended.

Comment: When verifying that the current time is different from the one saved is my problem, I cannot find how to do it without the user having to enter the web @ceejayoz

Comment: @AxelGarcia The next time the user comes back, you alert them that their subscription has ended based on the date. If they don't come back, you'd only need to do anything if there's something like a cron task running. If so, adjust that cron task to check their subscription, too.